# A time-out problem while connecting to git.gnuradio.org, how to solve it?

Tags: gnuradio

I'm trying to install the gnuradio and while trying to run this cmd line:

```
git clone --recursive git://git.gnuradio.org/gnuradio.git
```

I got stuck with this error:

```
Cloning into 'gnuradio'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.gnuradio.org:
git.gnuradio.org[0: 140.211.167.19]: errno=Connection timed out
```

Any idea of how to solve this connection problem, please?

Comment: Where did you find this URL? Also, to install GNU Radio, you usually don't have to download the source code (that's only necessary if you want to *modify* GNU Radio), but should use your system's native methods for simply installing GNU Radio from packages.

Comment: @Marcus Müller, I got it from here: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/UbuntuInstall

Comment: Literally FIRST sentence, in bold: **Note: this page is not update anymore** so. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio.git`

https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR

Comment: I'm trying to follow your recommendation where you refereed me to go to https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Tutorials to be more familiar with gnuradio .. now I'm really confused, your cmd line works, but why would they keep a non working problematic cmd line! How far I can trust these instructions! Also, I don't see where you got the above command line from, its not in the linked page you provided above!?

Comment: @Hadad, hmm... Indeed, I didn't notice that specific line was outdated in the wiki. Should be fixed now: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR